# classifying equilibria of dynamical system with multiple variables

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I am struggling on how to classify equilibria

The system I am working with is:

$\dot{x}=y$

$\dot{y}=-ay-k^2sinx$

where $a>0$

I managed to find the equilibria as $(0,0), (\pi,0),(-\pi,0)$ as well as all the other multiples of $\pi$

I got the Jacobian for $(0,0)$ to be

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-k^2&-a
\end{pmatrix}$$

with eigenvalues $$\lambda=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4k^2}}{2}$$

I got the Jacobian for $(\pi,0)$ to be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
k^2&-a
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
with eigenvalues $$\lambda=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4k^2}}{2}$$

I guess what I am asking is have I got it right so far, and if so, how would I go about classifying these when all I know is that $a>0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, as long as $0<2k\le a$, both eigenvalues are negative, for $a<2k$ they have negative real part. So it is always a sink, a node in the first case, a spiral in the second, with an improper node in the middle.

For the second case, note that $-a-\sqrt{a^2+4k^2}<0$ and $-a+\sqrt{a^2+4k^2}=\frac{4k^2}{a+\sqrt{a^2+4k^2}}>0$, so that you have a saddle point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I take it my previous calculations were correct? If I understand right, if 0<2k<a, then it is a stable node. And, if 2k=a then it is a stable degenerate node. One confusion I have is shouldn't the case for a<2k be a stable focus? I thought it was only a center if it had no real part...

Comment: @Anon: I think it's just a mistake and that the answer really meant to say that it's always *stable* (not that it's always a center).

Comment: @Anon: By the way, rather than looking at the eigenvalues, it's often easier to use the trace–determinant criterion, especially when the Jacobian matrix contains parameters.

Comment: Also, should it be 0<absolute(2k)<a, and a<absolute(2k) to take into account when k might be negative?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, I have not been taught that method, I will have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, I meant that it is a sink (as opposed to a source). I was somewhat lax with the notions for rotating/spiraling and non-rotating behavior. // Why would you take the base frequency $k$ negative? If both cases are equivalent, and nothing else is said, I would it always read as non-negative.

Comment: I am not sure as to the mechanics of it, I just thought that maybe I should account for all cases and was wondering if adding the \absolute(2k) would work.

Comment: Yes, if you want to cover all your bases, then use the absolute value. // Corrected the description, a center is what this is certainly not for $a\ne 0$.